# 番組のタイトルに「踊る」、どういう意味を表していますか？

Tags: meaning, nuances

踊る大捜査線

踊る！さんま御殿

この２つのテレビ番組だけかもしれませんが、タイトルの最初の言葉として、また、意味的に一見つながっていないようにも思ってしまうこの「踊る」は何を表していますか？そのまま踊ることではないことは間違いなさそうです。

私の推測としては、さんまの番組の場合、賑やかさを意味していると思います。しかし、踊る大捜査線の場合は違う気がします。紆余曲折を表しているかなぁと思ったけど、連想に過ぎないので、確信が持てません。

これに関しては日本語での説明をお願いできれば幸いです。

Comment: I've been curious about this for a while... 踊る!クレムリン御殿 is another example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

君が代の君なんかもそうですが、この手のものの解釈をはっきりさせようというのは私は少々野暮かなと思います。

しかしまぁ、大捜査線について言えば、「捜査」と「踊る」で思い浮かぶのは「踊らされる」という表現で、これは相手の謀略にはまって無駄なことをしてしまうという意味です。OPさんの考えに近いのはこれになるでしょう。

「おどる」についてもう一つ知ってもらいたい意味があります。それは「（新聞の紙面に）◯◯という文字/言葉が躍る」などの表現での「あちらこちらに入り乱れ、飛び跳ねる」という意味です。※「踊る」を狭義に解釈したら意味不明なのだから漢字の違いはもはや意味ない。

単に「踊る」であることに意味があるとすれば単純に「あわただしく、ワタワタしてるさま」というのがもっともらしいと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。とても参考になります。野暮ですか...定義とか逐語訳とかを求めていたら分かりますが、日本語をネイティブ並みに理解することが目標なら、上達するとともに定義よりも言葉の感覚を身に着けることが大事だと思います。そのためにこういう内容こそネイティブの方に解説していただきたいのです。大捜査線の場合、作家はこの「踊る」という言葉で人に伝わる何かがあるという思いで意図的に選んだ言葉だと考えています。監督もプロデューサーも納得したでしょう。その「何か」は何？と聞きたいのです。これに関しては、感覚が「無」に近い状態から、質問に書いたように、推測して理解しようとするけど、当てているのか大きく外れているのか分かる方法は日本人に聞く以外に無いと思います。そして、その伝わる「何か」は人によって違うでしょうけど、何人かからそれを聞くことによって言葉への感覚を磨く（場合によっては大きく調整する）ことができます。私にとってはこの類の質問が一番役に立ちます。面倒くさいと思う人もいるでしょうけど、私は本当に感謝します。

Answer (score 4):

このような「踊る」の使い方は一般的なものではなく、これらの番組名以外で使われているのを見たこともありません。なので推測ですが、これらの「踊る」は様々な出来事が起こること、激しい動き、スピード感、ダイナミックさなどを表現しているのだと思います。「紆余曲折」という単語には止まったり戻ったりしているようなネガティブなイメージがあるので、ちょっと「踊る」とは意味が違うような気がします。

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, I'm afraid, but one reason「踊る」got used in the program's title may be found in the [踊る!さんま御殿!!](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B8%8A%E3%82%8B!%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%E3%81%BE%E5%BE%A1%E6%AE%BF!!) Wikipedia page:

> 番組タイトル名の「踊る!」は以前、同局で放送されていた、さんまと所ジョージ司会のトークバラエティ番組『さんま・所のオシャベリの殿堂』で、さんまのしゃべる様子を所が「さんちゃんのトークは、いつも踊ってるねぇ〜」と表現したことに由来する。

Comment: "Not a real answer"... Maybe not but it helps